# Making VisualStudio2017 output to embedded output console

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to have an "embedded" console windows in VisualStudio 2017?

Basically what I want is when I hit F5 / Ctrl-F5, I don't want a separate cmd console to pop up, but rather have the program display the output to an embedded console, like the "Output" pane.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969469/visual-studio-2012-embedded-output-console-instead-of-cmd) but the question is pretty old itself and the answers involve writing a hack to do it, not checking a box in Options or something along those lines.

Is it possible, without using code to hack it in, to redirect the output so I only have to work with one window, the VS one?

If it matters, I need this for a C++ project.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option you can just activate by clicking on a some checkbox somewhere. It would be nice if MS added this to some future version of VS. You probably need some hack.

Comment: If there is output only (no interactive input) you can use DebugPrint api and family, that will appear in the Output window in VS. E.g. add an option "--output-debug" which turns this on for use while developing. You can then minimise the console and ignore it.