# How to intercept printf() in c++ code?

Tags: c++, stdio

I'm using static library that produces std output using printf(). How can i intercept it in order to show the output in my app and do some highlighting for example?

I have the sources of the lib and i can modify it slightly if needed.

Comment: There are answers to similar questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911147/how-to-redirect-printf-output-back-into-code
and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599109/redirecting-printf

Both suggest using a pipe to capture the stdout output, and setting up a separate thread/process to intercept it.  These answers might be worth a look for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to do it using `freopen(..);`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/

Comment: what? you didn't even say what reopen is, and for which OS

Comment: i've modified the answer and provided link

Answer (score 3):

> I have the sources of the lib and i can modify it slightly if needed.

Well, if you're really sure they're using `printf`, and you can build their code, you can use that against them so long as you don't have other places in there that use `printf`.

(I'm assuming a Unix-like platform, so there might need to be some modification to get this to work elsewhere.)

One thing you can do is redefine `printf` to point to your own version. Another is to write your own `printf` and link it in before the standard libraries. Neither of these routes are really what you'd consider recommended practice, though they should work. Neither route requires modification of the source of the library.

## Redefining printf

Here we just mess with the compiler's concept of `printf` by telling it that it's really a different function. Add something like this to your Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -Dprintf=redirected_printf
CXXFLAGS += -Dprintf=redirected_printf
```

(Some build systems use the variable `DEFINES` for this purpose; YMMV.)

This tells the compiler to replace every instance of the identifier `printf` with `redirected_printf`. It's the same as if you put `#define printf redirected_printf` at the top of every source file.

Now you just need to write the `redirected_printf` function. I prefer to pass the formatting off to another function in stdio, `vasprintf`, which does the same thing as `printf` except it takes a `va_list` instead of `...` and returns a pointer to a heap-allocated string with the output.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" int redirected_printf(const char * format, ...) {
    // Make formatted string.
    char* outstr = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    int result = vasprintf(&outstr, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if(result < 0) // Error occurred and `outstr` undefined if result < 0.
        return result;

    // Do something with the string in `outstr` here, like display it in a dialog.

    // Clean up and return.
    free(outstr);
    return result;
}
```

## Replacing printf

This is a bit trickier, because you have to write a function named `printf` that works like `replacement_printf` above, and then you have to convince the linker to link to your version instead of the standard library's. You might be able to just stick your `printf` in one of your compilation units and be done with it; when the clinker links the library you're redirecting to your sources, it will find your printf and link to it; then later when it sees the one in the standard library, it will just drop it because at that point nothing calls it.

If that doesn't work, you can try to put your `printf` into a library of your own with the `ar` and `ranlib` commands, then link that library after the one you're redirecting.

Note that if this library you're trying to redirect is a shared library (like a DLL or .so file), this probably won't work; it was linked to the standard `printf` back when it was built.

This route has a lot more caveats and depends on just how your linker works and a bunch of other things, so I don't recommend it, but I'm including it here for completeness.